# Can I distribute software that's using Microsoft's Visual Basic 2010 Express Edition? 

Tags: licensing

Am I within my rights to write and distribute software in compiled and source form using, in part, Microsoft's Visual Basic 2010 Express Edition? I have only the free, express version.

If it has anything to do with this, the license I am using is the [CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/).

Comment: How is your project using Visual Basic?

Comment: I can't make user interfaces in C (incompetent), so I'm writing a DLL which the Visual Basic program will be calling functions from when the user presses buttons, twirls dials, etc.

Comment: @Big Endian: do you want to distribute a software for which **you** are using MSVB 2010 Express, or is **your software** using the MSVB 2010 Express program package and you want to distribute your software together with the MSVB development environment? If the former is the case, *please* rephrase your question.

Comment: Considering its not possible for Microsoft to even know you used Visual Studio to compile your application there is nothing in the license itself that stops you from doing so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can distribute your source and binaries, under any license terms, for free or you can charge if you like.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969484/can-i-produce-a-commercial-application-using-visual-studio-express-2010

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the express versions does not impact your licensing models of software you create. They only limit the functionality that the IDE provides for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in a Microsoft forum, [Need help understanding the Microsoft EULA for Express Products](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/fi/Offtopic/thread/9c3cea8b-dd8a-420b-915f-5587f1578bda):

> Since the question is a license issue, you can call 1-800-426-9400 , Monday through Friday, 6:00 A.M. to 6:00 P.M. (Pacific Time) to speak directly to a Microsoft licensing specialist, and you can get more detail information from there. You can also visit the following site for more information and support on licensing issues:
>   http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/mla/default.aspx